# How else can "he's really inconsistent" be expressed ?

Tags: phrases, expressions

How else can "he's really inconsistent" be expressed ?

For an article about a sports person.

Comment: Have you tried using a thesaurus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [erratic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erratic)

Depending on whether you like the sports person in question, the Merriam-Webster dictionary also notes that erratic is a geological term for a boulder, indeed:

> a boulder or block of rock transported from its original resting place especially by a glacier

Comment: How about "his form was erratic at best" ?

Comment: That's how I would use erratic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say something like;

*His performance is a random variable with a high standard deviation.*

We may, similarly, express how frequently something varies by comparing it against phases of moon, tides, hill and valleys, mottled, or colorful etc.

Comment: If you could further substantiate your suggestions with a few examples that would be really helpful